# How to run Angular expressions inside of a HTML attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

### Description

I am using Bootstrap 4 tooltips to display additional information about prices. When adding text/html the documentation says to add this in the [title attribute](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/).  I have four different pricing items: spring price, fall price, semester price, retail price, retail spring, and retail fall. My goal is that when a tooltip shows it will only show the values that exist for retail. Unfortunately, when a value does not exist the text will still show. I've tried to use ng-if, ng-hide, and ng-show. I am guessing that Angular is not able to render the template because the logic is living inside of an HTML attribute string. Is this an instance where I would need to create a custom directive? If so, how would I tackle this problem?

[image]

### JSON

```
  $scope.plans = [ {
        name: "Early Move In", 
        priceFall: 265.85,
        priceSpring: 297.49,
        retail: 397.49,
        time: "I have an Elective All Access Meal Plan or 14 per Week Meal Plan and I am moving onto campus early",
        select: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit.",
        desc: "39 Meal Swipes <br/> + $25 Dining Dollars",
        perks: ["39 Meal Swipes", "$25 Dining Dollars"]  
    }];
```

### Angular Template ##

```
<p ng-if="plan.priceFall && plan.priceSpring">
 <span ng-if="plan.priceFall">{{plan.priceFall | currency}}  Fall</span> 
<br/>
 <span ng-if="plan.priceSpring">{{plan.priceSpring | currency }} Spring</span> 
<br/>
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="<p>Retail Price</p>
  <p ng-hide='plan.retail == null'>{{plan.retail | currency}} per semester</p>
     {{plan.retail}}
  <span ng-show='plan.retailFall != null'>{{plan.retailFall | currency}}  Fall</span>
  <br>
  <span ng-show='plan.retailSpring != null'>{{plan.retailSpring | currency }} Spring</span>" data-html="true">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-info fa-stack-1x" style="color:black"></i>
  </span>
  </p>
```

Comment: AngularJS directives that are added to the DOM need to be linked to the AngularJS framework with the [$compile service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile). For information on how to create custom directive, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Comment: In the example you posted all of the plans exist, so we cannot see the error you described in "action"? I mean, `priceFall: 265.85,
        priceSpring: 297.49,
        retail: 397.49` exist, so they should be in the tooltip. Could you recreate the issue using a plunker, jsfiddle, or any similar. A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help a lot in this case.